# How do I keep file references in sublime text 3?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is there any package in Sublime Text 3 that keeps / auto-updates file references when they are moved? Suppose I have 2 JS files

Example:

**routes.js**

`import {foo} from './bar`;

**foo.js**

`var foo = 1`;

But then I moved `foo.js` to a 'test' folder. So the reference will be changed to

`import {foo} from '../test/bar`.

Is there any built-in / package way for this one? Thanks